# On "short technical paper"

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

Several month ago I received the decision letter on my manuscript which was submitted to a credible journal. The paper was rejected; however, one of the reviewers suggested that the paper is better submitted elsewhere as a ***short technical paper***. So, I've searched but couldn't find any prestigious journal that receive such type of papers. Is there any specific type of journal/magazine for such papers (in computer science)?

Comment: What field you are in will be immensely helpful in answering this.

Comment: @Fomite, Computer Science - Data Mining

Comment: Short paper sometimes refers to extended abstract (normally 2-3 pages). Top-tier conferences usually have this kind of track.

Answer (score 3):

In most scientific disciplines, there are different journal tracks for "short papers" and "full papers."  Some of this may be leaking into computer science at this point, but at present the main mode of publication for shorter results in computer science is still typically a conference paper.

If you have not yet published your work in a conference, I would suggest looking for an appropriate conference to publish it in.  Depending on the size, some conferences even have "short paper" and "full paper" tracks---for example, one of the ones I regularly publish in has 10-page IEEE format full papers and 4-page IEEE format short papers.

If you *have* already published in a conference, then perhaps you should ask yourself whether this work really needs to become a journal paper. It is perfectly acceptable to have a piece of work published in a good conference and then not to extend it to a journal paper.